# How to add different names for multiple box-plot?

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot

I draw multiple boxplots of dissolved oxygen in  24 hours(captured in every 2 hours) in one figure but instead of numbers for boxplot, I want to put different names for boxplots.
for example, instead of 0 to 11 boxplot names , I need to put D/O_0, D/O_2,D/O_4,....,D/O_22.
This is my initial code.

```
sns.boxplot(data=[df2['DO_0'],df2['DO_2'],df2['DO_4'],df2['DO_6'],df2['DO_8'],df2['DO_10'],df2['DO_12'],df2['DO_14'],df2['DO_16'],df2['DO_18'],df2['DO_20'],df2['DO_22']],showmeans=True)
```

[image: Dissoved Oxygen Limit for every 2 hours.Start from 12AM]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the set_xticklabels() method :

```
fig = sns.boxplot(data=[df2['DO_0'],df2['DO_2'],df2['DO_4'],df2['DO_6'],df2['DO_8'],df2['DO_10'],df2['DO_12'],df2['DO_14'],df2['DO_16'],df2['DO_18'],df2['DO_20'],df2['DO_22']],showmeans=True)
fig.set_xticklabels(['D/O_0','DO_2',...])
```